# How to create _custom.scss to override variable in Bootstrap 4 alpha 6

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, frontend, gulp

I am trying to customize a Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 theme. I want to copy settings from  _variable.scss file to _custom.scss to override. But I didn't find _custom.scss file in source code. How do I add this _custom.scss file in my project?

Comment: You need to create file and add custom variable inside file.

Comment: If you accept an answer, then I can flag [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505841/how-to-override-bootstrap-variables-in-sass/47486673#47486673) as a duplicate.

Comment: bootstrap-4.3.1 
After experimenting with _custom.scss for a while I've found it easier to just edit _variables.scss. Merging of the old and the new versions after bootstrap update shouldn't be difficult. You have to edit bootstrap.scss anyway (add @import "custom"; in case of using _custom.scss).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noted your issue [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17322), [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23968) and [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/17021):

> ☐ Consider implementing a `_custom.scss` for easier, built-in variable overrides?

So because your Bootstrap 4 didn't ship with a `_custom.scss` file, you only need to re-create `bootstrap/scss/_custom.scss`.

Then edit `bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss` to what it's supposed to be:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "custom";
```

Then follow [**Customising variables**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/)

> Bootstrap 4 [supposedly] ships with a `_custom.scss` file for easy overriding of default variables in `/scss/_variables.scss`. Copy and paste relevant lines from there into the `_custom.scss` file, modify the values, and recompile your Sass to change our default values. **Be sure to remove the `!default` flag from override values.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not especially pleased with my current solution, but it simply works as a way to "override" variables in my current Angular implementation of Bootstrap 4.

1. Create a _custom.scss file in your project
2. Create a new bootstrap.scss in the project

   - Copy the contents of bootstrap.scss from Bootstrap to the new file (e.g., node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss)
   - Update each import with the correct file location relative to the new bootstrap.scss file
   - Add an import for your new custom file between variables and mixins
3. Update wherever you import Bootstrap to reference the newly created bootstrap.scss file

**Sample implementation:**
Folder structure:

```
app  
└── styles  
    ├── bootstrap.scss  
    └── _custom.scss
```

_custom.scss:

```
// For example, change links to be yellow
$link-color: yellow;
```

bootstrap.scss contains:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "custom";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
//etc.
```

app.component.scss (my location for any additional styles outside of Bootstrap):

```
@import "./styles/bootstrap"; // instead of @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you are using the source version of Bootstrap 4 alpha 6? Or haven't deleted **_custom.scss** by accident?

If you look at the [git repo for Boostrap 4 alpha 6](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/scss), **_custom.scss** is included.

Comment: Referenced a location that is not specific to Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 (has changed)