# Overriding bootstrap 4 primary button styling with scss

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

I am new to using SASS and I have found a lot of posts about how to change the primary button color, which is easy, but I would also like the change the border and the hover. The only way I can think of is to add an extra class which I have called 'basic'. Here is my code:

**SCSS**

```
$btn-bg: $bright-pink;    

@mixin button-variant($color, $background, $border) {
color: #fff;
background-color: $btn-bg;
border: 3px solid $btn-bg;

&:hover {
    color: $btn-bg;
    background-color: $transparent;
    border: 3px solid $btn-bg;
  }
}

.btn-primary.basic { @include button-variant
  (#fff,
  $btn-basic,
  3px solid $btn-bg); 
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary basic">Primary text</button>
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Can I override the primary button without adding an extra class?

Comment: *"but I would also like the change the border and the hover"* both the duplicates show this.. look at the 2nd and 3rd parameters of the button-variant mixin.

Comment: I've discovered my issue. I was loading the bootstrap.scss files after my custom override files in custom.scss, so nothing was being overwritten. Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565650/how-to-create-custom-scss-to-override-variable-in-bootstrap-4-alpha-6

Answer (score 2):

To create a new variant of a button, use the following SASS.

Then use "btn-primary basic" ass the class on the element.

```
$btn-background: #39a4d2;
$btn-border: #56a1c5;
$btn-color: #fff;

@mixin button-variant($background, $border, $color) {
    background-color: $btn-background;
    border: 2px solid $btn-border;
    color: #fff;

    &:hover {
        border: 2px solid $btn-background;
        color: $btn-color;
    }
}

.btn-primary {
    &.basic {
        @include button-variant($btn-background, $btn-border, $btn-color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this hold good for bootstrap 5 too ?